# javascript hide/show functionality doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Some of the javascripts on this site: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/onlinepizza3.php doesn't work in Firefox. What's the problem?

```
<script language="JavaScript">

     function OpenDiv(popUpDiv){
          popUpDiv.style.display="block";
          window.setTimeout("Hide();", 2000);
     }

     function OpenDiv(blanket){
          blanket.style.display="block";
          window.setTimeout("Hide();", 2000);
     }

     function Hide() {
          document.getElementById('popUpDiv').style.display='none'
          document.getElementById('blanket').style.display='none'
     }

</script>

<script language="JavaScript">

     function OpenCloseDiv(divName) {
          if (divName.style.display == "none") {
              divName.style.display="block";
          } else {
              divName.style.display="none";
          } 
     }

</script>
```

Comment: You have JS error on the page: `Image corrupt or truncated: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/images/background.jpg`. After this JS will not work on your site.

Comment: are you supposed to use plain JS or can you use also jQuery?

Comment: Don't use jQuery when it's not needed.

Comment: You are also missing `;` in the `.hide()` method

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Is there an error message? What should someone do on your site to replicate this error (other than look at your ads)? You should try Firebug to get more details on what's failing, then update your question.

Comment: @DidierG. actually that's also valid in JavaScript.

Comment: There is overloading in javascript. You have two times a `OpenDiv()` method.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt. It's valid but not a very good practice.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided isn't actually the problem.

If you look at the error console (I'm assuming you didn't), you'll see errors like "nr11 not defined". And this is why :

`<a onclick="OpenCloseDiv(nr11)"`

I don't know where you have the variable `nr11` defined, but you'll probably want to make it a string: `"nr11"` instead.

Comment: And in particular, the argument is called `divName` but it's treated as an `HTMLElement`, not a name...

Answer (score 1):

try to change window.setTimeout("Hide();", 2000); to window.setTimeout(Hide, 2000);

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function OpenCloseDiv(divName){
  var div = document.getElementById(divName);
  if (div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    div.style.display="none";
  }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenDiv(popUpDiv){
var div = document.getElementById(popUpDiv);
div.style.display="block";
window.setTimeout("Hide();", 2000);

}
function OpenDiv(blanket){
var div = document.getElementById(blanket);
div.style.display="block";
window.setTimeout("Hide();", 2000);

}
function Hide()
{
document.getElementById('popUpDiv').style.display='none'
document.getElementById('blanket').style.display='none'
}
</script>
```

and then added "" (  ) and it seems to work now. :)
Thank you for all your help! Really appreciate it!